# How can I make getter's call mandatory in the same class

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, design-patterns, annotations, java-7

I have this code:
How could I make the use of the getService() method mandatory in the getAll methode, that means if I call directly  `service.findAll()` compilation fails ?

Is it possible to create an annotation to prohibit the directly use of the field ?

```
@Named
@Profile("default")
public class AlfrescoVersionServiceImpl  {

   @Inject
   //Request Scope service
   private AlfrescoService service;

   @Resource
   private WebServiceContext webServiceContext;


   public List<Fichier> getAll(){
       return getService().findAll();
   }


   public AlfrescoService getService(){
       service.setEnPointAdress("--");
       if(webServiceContext.isUserInRole(role)){
           service.setRole("--");
       }
   }


}
```

Thank you in advance for your reply.

Comment: Your problems run deeper: Modifying a shared service is not thread safe.

Comment: @meriton the scope of the service is request,

Comment: NO answer please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could move the `service` field into a super class, and declare it `private` to prevent the subclass from accessing it, while leaving `getService()` `protected`.

Alternatively, you could configure the `AlfrescoService` in a `@Produces` method, so everyone asking for an `AlfrescoService` to be injected gets an instance that has already been configured.

Answer (score 1):

Inside `findAll()` you could examine the current stack trace using `Thread.getStackTrace()` and make sure the previous `StackTraceElement` is the class and method you want:

```
public List<Fichier> findAll() {
    StackTraceElement[] stack = Thread.getStackTrace();
    if(stack.length > 1) {
         // stack[0] is ourselves, stack[1] is who called us
         if(stack[1].getClassName().equals(...) && stack[1].getMethodName().equals(...) {
             // execute the business logic
         } 
    }
}
```

Just beware of a few things:

- This is a runtime check, so methods calling `findAll()` won't be flagged at compile time.
- According to the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getStackTrace--), the `getStackTrace()` method may not be permitted by some SecurityManagers, and some VMs may omit stack frames in rare cases.
- This may not be performant if you do this for every request.
- If the service is a Spring bean, you may have to deal with sorting through proxy classes to find the real caller (i.e. the previous stack frame before `findAll()` may be a spring generated proxy class).

An alternative would be to use an Aspect Oriented framework. For example, Spring AOP has the [ControlFlowPointcut](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-api-pointcuts-cflow) that can be used to match caller name, class, and package. This approach is a little more declarative, 
but relies on an extra library.